# Conditional Proof Tactic in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

I believe the title is pretty self explanatory : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_proof

I would like to have a tactic where I assume a proposition and proceed to find another one, if succeeded, then I have found that the first proposition **implies** the second one and this is put as an hypothesis in the context.

So for example `Ltac cp P Q` creates a subgoal `Q`and puts `P`in the context. If I can indeed reach the subgoal Q, then the subgoal is discharged and `P->Q` is added to the context. How can I achieve this ?

Edit: It is clear that while proving 
`assert (P->Q).
intro.`

does the job, but I cannot combine them into a Ltac tactic, it gives an error of `No focused proof (No proof-editing in progress).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define new tactics, you need to compose them with `;`.

```
Ltac cp P Q := assert (P -> Q); [ intro | ].
  (* Use intro in the first subgoal of assert *)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already such a tactic, it's called `enough`, as "it is enough to show that P".  It assumes `P` and you now get to finish your proof using `P`.  When you're done, you have to prove `P`.

If it is easy to finish, you can use `by` (in the same as for `assert`).  I often do `enough (bla bla) by (subst; auto).` or something similar, which leaves me with the goal `bla bla`.

You may also find this tactic useful, i.e. if you don't want to type the entire complicated antecedent into the `enough` statement:

```
Ltac postpone_antecedent H :=
  match type of H with  ?A -> _ =>
    let Q := fresh in enough A as Q ; [specialize (H Q) | ]
  end.
```